# Jasper Reports sum a field conditionally based on the value of another field

Tags: variables, jasper-reports, expression, conditional-statements

In Jasper Reports, can you accumulate a variable (a double; calculation = Sum) of Field (`$F{adr}`, a double) based on the value of a different field (`$F{hce}`, a string);

I have tried

```
$F{hce} == "Y" ? $F{adr} : 0
```

I thought I had used this capability in JR b4, but I can't make it work now. It just comes up with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right lines. Check your field is in the correct band. Try dragging a numeric field into the summary band. You should get an option to aggregate as a sum. You can then edit the expression with a ternary as above and that should allow you to selectively sum stuff. The band, datatype and reset and increment type have to be correctly set in the properties.